How can I round window corners smoothly with C and Xlib?
I have tried to use XCreatePixmap/XFillArc/XFillRectangle/XShapeCombineMask to round corners but it seems can not make pixmap mask smoothly. For details of the unsmooth renderings, please see:
https://guoshimin.users.sourceforge.net/others/upload/corners.png
How can I round window corners smoothly with C and Xlib ?

I don't know what your standard of "smoothly" is. Please show the corners you have alongside those you want.
